# Getting Values from Multiselect dropdown Jquery Boostrap with Flask

Tags: jquery, python, twitter-bootstrap, post, flask

I am writing a bootstrap and jQuery web form in `Flask` and `Jinga` templates trying to get the value of the multiselect dropdown when I click an Update Data button.

Template Code:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post">
<fieldset>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="account_picks">Select the Account(s):</label>
<div class="col-md-4">
<select id="account_picks" multiple="multiple" value="{{request.form.account_picks}}">

            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
  </select>
</div>
</div>


<script id="example">

$(function() {

    $('#account_picks').multiselect({
        includeSelectAllOption: true

    });

    $("#account_picks").multiselect('selectAll', true);
    $("#account_picks").multiselect('updateButtonText');

});</script>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-sucess" id="update" value="Update Data"/>
</div>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

In the Flask file I am trying to get the value with `request.form['account_picks']`, which works great for all other types of entry boxes, but doesn't seem to work for the multiselect.

Error:

> Bad Request
>
> The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using the getlistfunction()

```
account_picks = request.form.getlist('account_picks')
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: I hadn't tried that but looks to return a blank list, despite the two options.

Comment: Perhaps this answer would help you:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23557063/passing-value-from-a-drop-down-menu-to-a-flask-template

Comment: `getlist()` seems to go by name, rather than Id. I added a name tag and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome, feel free to accept the answer if this solved your problem.

Comment: You can also use it with other methods such as request.POST.getlist('account_picks')